# Is there a variable for accessing the version number for a given deployed cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

GCP displays the version number of a deployed cloud function in the console. At the moment there isn't a [system environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var) which contains information about the deployment - there is no version, nor deployment date.

Given that version updates take considerable time to update (30 seconds +) and propagate, such version information would be useful to wield.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recently-released nodejs10 runtime environment now includes an
[officially documented environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes)
`K_REVISION` that contains the deployment version of a cloud function.

From inspection, it also seems that the python37 and older nodejs8 environments
include an unofficial environment variable `X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION`
that happens to contain the deployment version.

This snippet works on nodejs10 and unofficially works on nodejs8:

```
exports.helloVersion = (req, res) => {
  console.log(process.env);
  const version = process.env.K_REVISION || process.env.X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION || "UNKNOWN";
  console.log(`Running version ${version}`);
  res.status(200).send(`Running version ${version}\n`)
};
```

Deploying and testing:

```
$ gcloud functions deploy helloVersion --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http
versionId: '8'
$ curl https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/helloVersion
Running version 8

$ gcloud functions deploy helloVersion --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http
versionId: '9'
$ curl https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/helloVersion
Running version 9
```

Of course, the `K_REVISION` environment variable on nodejs10 is probably
the way to go, given that it's mentioned in the official documentation. 
The `X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION` environment variable isn't officially
mentioned, so it's probably a bad idea to rely on it for something important,
but I've found that it might be helpful to display or include opportunistically 
when debugging, deploying, and testing interactively.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to get the version number of a function at runtime.  You always have the option of assigning some value yourself and put it in an environment variable using the [`--set-env-vars`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--set-env-vars) flag in gcloud.

If your goal is to figure out if a function invocation is actually running the code you just deployed while iterating during development, it's effective to simply `console.log('deployed')` at the global scope of your function.  The message will appear in the console logs after the deployment is complete, and you can wait for that message to appear in the log in order to know when your new code is active.  Everything logged after that log should be from your latest code.

Comment: Nice, that's probably enough, but it would be amazing if that console log included the version number too!

Comment: I totally agree.

Comment: But still, the ability to update a batch function to respond with `res.status(200).send(environment.version);` would eliminate the need to open the log viewer.

Comment: Again, you can specify your own environment var to do with what you want.  Could even be a random UUID, if all you need is a visual match.

Comment: true, it's not perfect (it necessitates command-line interaction), but it's a workaround.

Answer (score -1):

Check [`gcloud version`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/version), which prints out version info.

Comment: Indeed this returns some version numbers, but they are for the SDK components (`gcloud` and its dependencies), rather than the version of a deployed Function application, which is what OP was asking.