# Firebase Functions : deploy version or timestamp (for logging)

Tags: google-cloud-functions

What would be the best automatic available value to return (eg. in a HTTP function) that gives an unique indication of the current deployed version or timestamp of my functions (so not version of the node runtime)? Looking for e.g. a number or timestamp that gets incremented automatically when I do a new deploy of my functions.

I thought using this:

```
function currentFileTimestamp() {
  var stats = fs.statSync("./index.js");
  var mtime = new Date(stats.mtime);
  return mtime
}
```

But this always seams to return Tue Jan 01 1980 00:00:01 GMT+0000
Does the Firebase Admin API have a "current deployed version" timestamp or something that we could use?

Comment: Hi @HixField it seems that there isn't many official ways to achieve that, other the on Node.js. There are some alternatives and Python and Java as it seems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991677/is-there-a-variable-for-accessing-the-version-number-for-a-given-deployed-cloud) as well, but it would depend on the language you are using. Could you please give it a try checking if this linked case helps you?

Comment: Hi @gso_gabriel that is exactly what I was looking for. Will you formulate an answer so I can accept and credit you? Or are you not interested and shall I answer my own question?

Comment: Hi @HixField glad to hear it helped you! I have posted for you to accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some alternatives that you can give it a try. On Node.js 10 runtime environment there is an environment variable - more information [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_10_and_subsequent_runtimes) - called `K_REVISION`, where you can find the value from the version of your Cloud Function.

For Python and older Node.js versions there is also an environment variable called `X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION` that you can also check for the deployed version.

You can get more details on how to use them, with examples in this similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991677/is-there-a-variable-for-accessing-the-version-number-for-a-given-deployed-cloud).

Answer (score 0):

I just deployed a test function to Google Cloud Functions using the `python 3.10` runtime and can confirm that the environment variable is called `K_REVISION` as [wheatazogg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1438064/wheatazogg) discusses in his post about nodejs10

```
import os

def testdeployfunction(data,context) :
    for name, value in os.environ.items() :
        print("{0}: {1}".format(name,value))
    return 'OK'
```

returns:

[image: screenshot log of function triggered]