# Accessing version number for deployed Cloud Function in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Similar to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991677/is-there-a-variable-for-accessing-the-version-number-for-a-given-deployed-cloud) asked for node.js, I am wondering if there is some way for the deployed Cloud Function in python to access its own version number. I cant find the answer to this anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: From the best of my understanding, the verison number seriously depends on how the cloud function is deployed... It may be that the number is always '1'.

Comment: Each time you deploy a new revision, the version number increments by 1. So I want to always be able to write the version number as a part of a pubsub message to track when the message was produced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `python 3.7`, use the old version `X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION`:

**python 3.7** :

```
import os

def function_Version(request):
    ver = os.environ.get('X_GOOGLE_FUNCTION_VERSION')
    return ver
```

then for **python 3.9** use `K_REVISION` :

```
import os

def function_Version(request):
    ver = os.environ.get('K_REVISION')
    return ver
```